# Petclinic Spring example returns "Failed to load resource"

Tags: spring

I just downloaded the petclinic application from this site: https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/.

I imported it in Eclipse, the server is Tomcat 7, the application is working but the static data, like images and scripts are not:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) petclinic/static/styles/petclinic.css

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) /petclinic/static/images/pets.png

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) /petclinic/static/images/springsource-logo.png
```

Answer (score 2):

Petclinic sample is a bit outdated and has a known issue on Tomcat, see [SPR-7893](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7893).

If you want to make it work on Tomcat nonetheless, you need to create a folder named `src/main/webapp/static` and move `html`, `images` and `styles` folders there.

Comment: I created the folder src/main/webapp/static and move html, images and styles folders to it, the images and styles are still broken.